# Check status of 11-Minute Kernel mode using adjtimex

Tags: linux, debian, time, clock, ntpd

I have a Debian Buster system which has the Kernel compiled without the `CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC` since I DO NOT want the 11-minute kernel mode to be on. However, I wanted to check if this change actually worked.

So I checked the `status` field from the output of `adjtimex --print` command. The `status` field is `24577` or `0b110000000000001`.

According to the man page here - https://linux.die.net/man/8/adjtimex, it seems that the `64` bit of the `status` field is `not set`, which according to here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/55432 means that the `11-minute mode` is on.

This is contradictory to what I expected when I compiled the kernel with the `CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC` as `not set`. How can I reliably check if the 11-minute mode is actually turned off, or am I interpreting the output of `adjtimex` incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Just to clear possible confusion by anyone reading this answer: when Linux is running, there are (usually) two clocks: the "main" clock is the system clock, which is usually CPU-based. The other clock is the persistent hardware clock (RTC). When the system is shut down, the system clock loses its time and only the persistent hardware clock keeps the correct wall-clock time.)

The primary meaning of the `64` bit of the `status` field of `adjtimex` is "the system clock is/is not being synchronized by NTP or other time source". The 11-minute mode used to be tightly coupled to that: if the system clock was being syncronized, then the RTC would be updated every 11 minutes; if not, then it wouldn't be.

The option to disable system clock-to-RTC transfer every 11 minutes by `CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC` was a later addition.

Disabling `CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC` cuts the connection between the system clock synchronization and RTC 11-minute updates. You can check the relevant kernel source code, which in Debian Buster's standard 4.19.xx kernel is the function `sync_rtc_clock()` in [kernel/time/ntp.c at line #532](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/ntp.c?h=v4.19.231#n532). You can see that when `CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC` is not set, the function returns early without doing anything:

```
static void sync_rtc_clock(void)
{
    unsigned long target_nsec;
    struct timespec64 adjust, now;
    int rc;

    if (!IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC))   <--- If CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC is not enabled,
        return;                           <--- return immediately.

    ktime_get_real_ts64(&now);

    adjust = now;
    if (persistent_clock_is_local)
        adjust.tv_sec -= (sys_tz.tz_minuteswest * 60);

    /*
     * The current RTC in use will provide the target_nsec it wants to be
     * called at, and does rtc_tv_nsec_ok internally.
     */
    rc = rtc_set_ntp_time(adjust, &target_nsec);
    if (rc == -ENODEV)
        return;

    sched_sync_hw_clock(now, target_nsec, rc);
}
```

In other words, disabling `CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC` makes the `11-minute mode` effectively a no-op.

More experimentally, you could use the kernel profiling tools to monitor the `rtc_set_time()` function over a suitable multiple of 11 minutes and see how often it gets called. If you find the answer is 0 times, you'll know that the hardware RTC clock is not being adjusted by 11-minute mode *nor by anything else*.

Comment: +1! Does CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC = n disable the 11-minute mode only or does this as well disable the sync at shutdown time as possibly requested in /etc/conf.d/hwclock by a statement clock_systohc="YES" ?

Comment: Or even running hwclock --systohc ?

Comment: @MC68020 The CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC only controls the effect of kernel  *11-minute mode*; it is not a generic "write protection switch" for the RTC. As the sync at shutdown and any explicit `hwclock --systohc` are user-space operations that require root permissions anyway, the administrator can always opt to not do those operations in the first place, e.g. by setting the `clock_systohc` in the `/etc/conf.d/hwclock` file you mentioned to "no", and by otherwise choosing to not run `hwclock --systohc`.